# Custom Ubuntu Distro - Remastersys - No Set Settings

Tags: 12.04, custom-distributions, remastersys

I am trying to create my own custom distro from Ubuntu 12.04 after watching a video on Youtube.

My problem is when I boot my LiveUSB it looks exactly like a normal boot of Ubuntu 12.04 other than the cursor I changed.

But I found that if I went into tweak tool (This is logged into Gnome environment) almost all my settings were there, just not set. My icon pack was there but not selected by default, my extensions were there - just none were on and things like the trash bin on the desktop were all off.

So basically, I am trying to find a way to make my Live Edition default exactly like what I am using just without all my personal data.

Answer (score 0):

Remastersys has 2 modes of operation: distribution, and backup. Distribution mode allows you to install packages and add files, but it doesn't save user configuration information. Backup mode saves everything including user configuration changes. The reason your settings aren't there is because they are not system wide, they are user specific, and as such will only appear in your user account. Since settings are done on a per user basis any new user accounts will also get the applications default settings rather than your user's settings. Remastersys cannot help you accomplish your goal because it doesn't alter an applications default settings.

The closest thing you can do would be create a backup so that the pre-included user account on the disc will have settings saved, but as mentioned before newly created additional accounts won't as they get the applications default settings.

Answer (score 0):

simple ,

create a new user acount , and customize it , (or use your own .....)

next  make sure no user data is in your home account , use bleachbit 
http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux

please check if there are no documents , movies , music left in your home folder , if so backup them and delete them in your home folder.

now copy with sudo premissions your home folder incl all hidden files , to /etc/skel/

then create a new user account and login to that account to see if all your settings are there.

is so , your good to go , run remastersys or relinux , both work fine.

best way to use remastersys is from commandline , sudo remastersys dist cdfs

at finish of that command , sudo remastersys dist iso nameofyourdist.iso